# Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address payable[] storage ref

Tags: ethereum, solidity

In the statement `players.push(msg.sender);` I am getting following error:

**Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address payable[] storage ref.**

Thus I cannot push to address payable array in solidity. What's the workaround here?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.7.0;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address payable[] public players;

    constructor() {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        players.push(msg.sender);            // ERROR IN THIS LINE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you're compiling with Solidity 0.7, everything works fine.

This error shows in Solidity 0.8, and it's because in 0.8 `msg.sender` is not automatically `payable` anymore. So you need to make it `payable` first:

```
players.push(payable(msg.sender));
```

---

From the docs page [Solidity v0.8.0 Breaking Changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/080-breaking-changes.html):

> *The global variables `tx.origin` and `msg.sender` have the type `address` instead of `address payable`. One can convert them into `address payable` by using an explicit conversion, i.e., `payable(tx.origin)` or `payable(msg.sender)`.*

Answer (score 8):

I had to explicitly convert `msg.sender` into `payable` to get it working.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0;

contract Lottery {
    address payable public manager;
    address payable[] public players;
    
    constructor() {
        manager = payable(msg.sender);
    }
    
    function enter() public payable {
        players.push(manager);
    } 
}
```

References:

[Casting from address to address payable](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64109/68718)

[TypeError: push is not detected as a function for address payable dynamic array](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/87811/68718)