# Chainlink - [python/brownie] CompilerError: solc returned the following errors

Tags: python, solidity, smartcontracts, brownie

I am trying to compile the code below but I can't compile it correctly. Seems there is compile error but I can't understand what I am doing wrong? I thought was the pragma version or brownie config.yaml but the issue seems not related to them.

Can someone help me with this?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

//definition of the contract lottery: the contract is based on the 4 functions below
contract Lottery {
    address payable[] public players;
    uint256 public usdEntryFee;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal ethUsdPriceFeed;
    enum LOTTERY_STATE {
        OPEN,
        CLOSE,
        WINNER
    }
    LOTTERY_STATE public lottery_state;

    // 0
    // 1
    // 2

    constructor(address _priceFeedAddress) public {
        usdEntryFee = 50 * (10**18);
        ethUsdPriceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeedAddress); //converting the optimal price feed
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        //in order to pay player we need that the funciont enter is "payable" and also wee need to track the players who join to the lottery
        // $50 minimum enter
        require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE);
        require(msg.value >= getEntranceFee(), "Not enough ETH!");
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 price, , , ) = ethUsdPriceFeed.lastestRoundData();
        uint256 adjustedPrice = uint256(price) * 10**10; //18 decimals
        // $50, $2,000 / ETH
        // 50/2,000
        // 50 * 100000/2000
        uint256 costToEnter = (usdEntryFee * 10**18) / adjustedPrice;
        return costToEnter;
    }

    function startLottery() public onlyOwner {
        require(
            lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSE,
            "Lottery is closed, You can't start a new lottery!"
        );
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN;
    }

    //function that determinate the winner of Lottery with a pseudonumber
    function endLottery() public onlyOwner {
        uint256(
            keccack256(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    nonce,
                    msg.sender,
                    block.difficulty, //can actually be manipulated by miners >> solution Chainlink VRF
                    block.timestamp
                )
            )
        ) % players.lenght;
    }
}
```

---

here there is the output of terminal:

```
Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.8.10
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.   
  --> contracts/lottery.sol:12:5:
   |
12 |     constructor(address _priceFeedAddress) public {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).


TypeError: Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address payable[] storage ref.
  --> contracts/lottery.sol:20:9:
   |
20 |         players.push(msg.sender);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^

(base) PS C:\Users\ssida\Desktop\demos\smartcontract-lottery>
```

---

brownie config here:

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - "@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.2.1"
```

Any help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799537/member-push-not-found-or-not-visible-after-argument-dependent-lookup-in-addres

Comment: fixed thank you @wxker. if i run again i got this: CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
  --> contracts/Lottery.sol:45:36:
   |
45 |     function startLottery() public onlyOwner {

Do you think is for the same reason? Thank you.

Comment: `onlyOwner` is not defined anywhere