# Why doesn't this smart contract compile?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to compile an existing ERC20 smart contract that is actually deployed on the Avalanche network. I'd like to deploy it on another compatible testnet network (such as Ethereum Ropsten) in order to see how it works, and if it is not a scam smart contract.
The source code does not compile in Remix IDE. There is an error stating :

> TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for
> objects of type "address payable", not "address".
> --> contracts/superstaking.sol:148:3: | 148 | msg.sender.transfer(totalAmount); | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The source code of the smart contract is :

```
/**
 *Submitted for verification at snowtrace.io on 2022-03-04
*/

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
 
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract 4V4XStaker {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    uint256 constant public INVEST_MIN_AMOUNT = 0.05 ether;
    uint256[] public REFERRAL_PERCENTS = [60, 30, 10];
    uint256 constant public PROJECT_FEE = 120;
    uint256 constant public PERCENT_STEP = 3;
    uint256 constant public WITHDRAW_FEE = 1000; //In base point
    uint256 constant public PERCENTS_DIVIDER = 1000;
    uint256 constant public TIME_STEP = 1 days;
    
    uint256 public totalStaked;
    uint256 public totalRefBonus;

    struct Plan {
        uint256 time;
        uint256 percent;
    }

    Plan[] internal plans;

    struct Deposit {
        uint8 plan;
        uint256 percent;
        uint256 amount;
        uint256 profit;
        uint256 start;
        uint256 finish;
    }

    struct User {
        Deposit[] deposits;
        uint256 checkpoint;
        address referrer;
        uint256[3] levels;
        uint256 bonus;
        uint256 totalBonus;
    }

    mapping (address => User) internal users;

    uint256 public startUNIX;
    address payable public commissionWallet;

    event Newbie(address user);
    event NewDeposit(address indexed user, uint8 plan, uint256 percent, uint256 amount, uint256 profit, uint256 start, uint256 finish);
    event Withdrawn(address indexed user, uint256 amount);
    event RefBonus(address indexed referrer, address indexed referral, uint256 indexed level, uint256 amount);
    event FeePayed(address indexed user, uint256 totalAmount);

    constructor(address payable wallet, uint256 startDate) public {
        require(!isContract(wallet));
        require(startDate > 0);
        commissionWallet = wallet;
        startUNIX = startDate;

        plans.push(Plan(14, 80));
        plans.push(Plan(21, 75));
        plans.push(Plan(28, 70));
        plans.push(Plan(14, 80));
        plans.push(Plan(21, 75));
        plans.push(Plan(28, 70));
    }

    function invest(address referrer, uint8 plan) public payable {

        require(msg.value >= INVEST_MIN_AMOUNT,"too small");
        require(plan < 6, "Invalid plan");

        uint256 fee = msg.value.mul(PROJECT_FEE).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER);
        commissionWallet.transfer(fee);
        emit FeePayed(msg.sender, fee);

        User storage user = users[msg.sender];

        if (user.referrer == address(0)) {
            if (users[referrer].deposits.length > 0 && referrer != msg.sender) {
                user.referrer = referrer;
            }

            address upline = user.referrer;
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (upline != address(0)) {
                    users[upline].levels[i] = users[upline].levels[i].add(1);
                    upline = users[upline].referrer;
                } else break;
            }
        }

        if (user.referrer != address(0)) {

            address upline = user.referrer;
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                if (upline != address(0)) {
                    uint256 amount = msg.value.mul(REFERRAL_PERCENTS[i]).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER);
                    users[upline].bonus = users[upline].bonus.add(amount);
                    users[upline].totalBonus = users[upline].totalBonus.add(amount);
                    emit RefBonus(upline, msg.sender, i, amount);
                    upline = users[upline].referrer;
                } else break;
            }

        }

        if (user.deposits.length == 0) {
            user.checkpoint = block.timestamp;
            emit Newbie(msg.sender);
        }

        (uint256 percent, uint256 profit, uint256 finish) = getResult(plan, msg.value);
        user.deposits.push(Deposit(plan, percent, msg.value, profit, block.timestamp, finish));

        totalStaked = totalStaked.add(msg.value);
        emit NewDeposit(msg.sender, plan, percent, msg.value, profit, block.timestamp, finish);
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        User storage user = users[msg.sender];

        uint256 totalAmount = getUserDividends(msg.sender);
        uint256 fees = totalAmount.mul(WITHDRAW_FEE).div(10000);
           totalAmount = totalAmount.sub(fees);

        uint256 referralBonus = getUserReferralBonus(msg.sender);
        if (referralBonus > 0) {
            user.bonus = 0;
            totalAmount = totalAmount.add(referralBonus);
        }

        require(totalAmount > 0, "User has no dividends");

        uint256 contractBalance = address(this).balance;
        if (contractBalance < totalAmount) {
            totalAmount = contractBalance;
        }

        user.checkpoint = block.timestamp;
        

        msg.sender.transfer(totalAmount);

        emit Withdrawn(msg.sender, totalAmount);

    }

    function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getPlanInfo(uint8 plan) public view returns(uint256 time, uint256 percent) {
        time = plans[plan].time;
        percent = plans[plan].percent;
    }

    function getPercent(uint8 plan) public view returns (uint256) {
        if (block.timestamp > startUNIX) {
            return plans[plan].percent.add(PERCENT_STEP.mul(block.timestamp.sub(startUNIX)).div(TIME_STEP));
        } else {
            return plans[plan].percent;
        }
    }

    function getResult(uint8 plan, uint256 deposit) public view returns (uint256 percent, uint256 profit, uint256 finish) {
        percent = getPercent(plan);

        if (plan < 3) {
            profit = deposit.mul(percent).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER).mul(plans[plan].time);
        } else if (plan < 6) {
            for (uint256 i = 0; i < plans[plan].time; i++) {
                profit = profit.add((deposit.add(profit)).mul(percent).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER));
            }
        }

        finish = block.timestamp.add(plans[plan].time.mul(TIME_STEP));
    }

    function getUserDividends(address userAddress) public view returns (uint256) {
        User storage user = users[userAddress];

        uint256 totalAmount;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < user.deposits.length; i++) {
            if (user.checkpoint < user.deposits[i].finish) {
                if (user.deposits[i].plan < 3) {
                    uint256 share = user.deposits[i].amount.mul(user.deposits[i].percent).div(PERCENTS_DIVIDER);
                    uint256 from = user.deposits[i].start > user.checkpoint ? user.deposits[i].start : user.checkpoint;
                    uint256 to = user.deposits[i].finish < block.timestamp ? user.deposits[i].finish : block.timestamp;
                    if (from < to) {
                        totalAmount = totalAmount.add(share.mul(to.sub(from)).div(TIME_STEP));
                    }
                } else if (block.timestamp > user.deposits[i].finish) {
                    totalAmount = totalAmount.add(user.deposits[i].profit);
                }
            }
        }

        return totalAmount;
    }

    function getUserCheckpoint(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256) {
        return users[userAddress].checkpoint;
    }

    function getUserReferrer(address userAddress) public view returns(address) {
        return users[userAddress].referrer;
    }

    function getUserDownlineCount(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        return (users[userAddress].levels[0], users[userAddress].levels[1], users[userAddress].levels[2]);
    }

    function getUserReferralBonus(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256) {
        return users[userAddress].bonus;
    }

    function getUserReferralTotalBonus(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256) {
        return users[userAddress].totalBonus;
    }

    function getUserReferralWithdrawn(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256) {
        return users[userAddress].totalBonus.sub(users[userAddress].bonus);
    }

    function getUserAvailable(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256) {
        return getUserReferralBonus(userAddress).add(getUserDividends(userAddress));
    }

    function getUserAmountOfDeposits(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256) {
        return users[userAddress].deposits.length;
    }

    function getUserTotalDeposits(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256 amount) {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < users[userAddress].deposits.length; i++) {
            amount = amount.add(users[userAddress].deposits[i].amount);
        }
    }

    function getUserDepositInfo(address userAddress, uint256 index) public view returns(uint8 plan, uint256 percent, uint256 amount, uint256 profit, uint256 start, uint256 finish) {
        User storage user = users[userAddress];

        plan = user.deposits[index].plan;
        percent = user.deposits[index].percent;
        amount = user.deposits[index].amount;
        profit = user.deposits[index].profit;
        start = user.deposits[index].start;
        finish = user.deposits[index].finish;
    }

    function isContract(address addr) internal view returns (bool) {
        uint size;
        assembly { size := extcodesize(addr) }
        return size > 0;
    }
}

library SafeMath {

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, "SafeMath: division by zero");
        uint256 c = a / b;

        return c;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address payable\[\] storage ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66799537/member-push-not-found-or-not-visible-after-argument-dependent-lookup-in-addres)

Comment: The auditor of the smart contract confirms that the source code is exactly the one that I have pasted here. So that would mean that it should compile as is, without any modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about the Solidity version that you're compiling with.

The `pragma` statement states that this source code is compatible with all versions from `0.4.22` included to `0.9.0` excluded - but that's not completely true. It's only compatible with versions up to `0.7.x`. If you're compiling with Solidity version `0.8.0` and later, you need to typecast the `msg.sender` type `address` to type `address payable`.

```
payable(msg.sender).transfer(totalAmount);
```

Comment: Thank you ! It compiles with version 0.4.22 :)